# Minimum amount of ViewHolders in a RecyclerView?

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-viewholder

I am using a modified TwoWayView https://github.com/lucasr/twoway-view

I am using the `SpannableGridLayoutManager` so my views can all be different sizes.
If my first few views are large in size then scrolling becomes laggy because the amount of views changes (so the amount of view holders changes)

I have the method `setMaxRecycledViews` which works great after I've scrolled a bit.

I've also tried playing with `getExtraLayoutSpace` but I don't think that is what I should be using.

Basically I have a grid that can have views of different sizes but they have the same layout. At the top there is a view that takes up the whole space and below that is a view that takes up the whole width. So it loads 2 view holders, but then when I scroll it quickly needs 16 view holders and that causes a lag.

Is there a way to force a minimum amount of ViewHolders?

Comment: You can set visibility of your views to VISIBLE, INVISIBLE(not visible but occupies space or GONE(no space occupied) as an option

Answer (score 3):

This did the trick for me

```
    RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool recycledViewPool = new RecyclerView.RecycledViewPool();
    recycledViewPool.setMaxRecycledViews(0, 16);
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getContext());
    for (int i = 0; i < 16; i++) {
        MyAdapter.SimpleViewHolder simpleViewHolder = myAdapter.createViewHolder(mTwoWayView, 0);
        recycledViewPool.putRecycledView(simpleViewHolder);
    }
    recyclerView.setRecycledViewPool(recycledViewPool);
```

Basically before starting anything increase the max scraps to 15 (from the default of 5) and add 12 scraps. This way when the grid layout changes from showing 1 to 16 the view holders are already in the pool.